# Reading images from sd-card like res

Tags: android

I have mass of int, witch I use like this:

```
 final int[] iconN = new int[] { R.drawable.arrow_left_a,
   R.drawable.arrow_right_a, R.drawable.sound_on,
   R.drawable.sound_off };
```

To set image on click:

```
final ImageView bL = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iV1);
  bL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
       bL.setImageResource(iconN[0]);
   }
  });
```

This files are in drowable. What I need to do when I'll work with files from sd-card the same way?
I try to do something like this:

```
final int[] iconC = new int[] {
            Integer.parseInt(iA.getSdDir() + "/Files/Colors/arrow_left_a.png"),
            Integer.parseInt(iA.getSdDir() + "/Files/Colors/arrow_right_a.png") };
```

But it's wrong and I get an err:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '/mnt/sdcard/izuchaika//Files/Colors/arrow_left_a.png' as integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a numberFormatException because you're trying to parse the fully-qualified path name for a file as an integer. That won't be possible.

To use the image from the SD card, you have to read it into a bitmap and then pass that to the image view:

```
bl.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(iA.getSdDir()+"/Files/Colors/arrow_left_a.png"));
```